# Ipython and Curses on Windows

Tags: ipython, qtconsole

I have been trying all sorts of sourceforge projects that try to port GNU functionality to Windows, with the goal to create a very GNU aware Ipython profile providing the best terminal environment I know how (on Windows that is).

How close is QtConsole to having the ability of running something like Curses through the IpyQt frontend?

(The key here, is that I want the DPI aware rich text of QtConsole. Would knock the socks off most of the Windows terminal alternatives.)

Is that possibility even in sight, or is that a match that will likely not happen? I have never emulated a VT100 in my spare time, how much does QtConsole look like one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not really in sight. The Qt console has some support for control characters, so it can do things like coloured text, but it's definitely not enough to support curses, and we're not really interested in going down that route.

The code is all in the open if you want to try to make it into a full terminal emulator. But I rather hope there are better starting points for terminal emulators in Windows.

Comment: If you really want curses (or a terminal emulator), there are definitely other options in Windows. But I am really stuck on the idea of using QtConsole as the base for a cross-platform *pyTerm* environment. Just trying to get a feel for my boundaries.